# connect_kwargs not attribute of open

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, ssh, fabric

I wanted to connect to a server, but it gave me an error that I need a method of SSH athentication, so I simply made a key-value pair with "open()" and "connect_kwargs".

As I specified earlier this is my code:

```
from fabric import Connection
import socket
uinaaaa = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
uinaaaa.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
xin = uinaaaa.getsockname()[0]
PERSONA = Connection(f"user@{xin}")
PERSONA.open(connect_kwargs={'password': "LOSER"})
print("Ok, now you will learn all the server's commands!")
YUIA = PERSONA.run("help")
print(YUIA.standout)
print("If you want to learn more, type man, after that, a space, and then the command to learn more!")
```

but I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    PERSONA.open(connect_kwargs={'password': "LOSER"})
TypeError: open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'connect_kwargs'
```

I don't know how to fix this. Is it an entirely differnet function then "open()" or just a different argument than connect_kwargs? Please help!

Comment: `connect_kwargs` is an incorrect argument.  So the real question is, _why are you doing that?_  Did you copy that from some example code?

Comment: Yes, but well I need to know how to fix it. When I was looking for help, I found that I need some way of SSH authentication, so I used the open function. When it gave me an error I seeked out more help, but I guess it was wrong, so I don't know what to do anymore. Could you please help?

Comment: That is an incorrect argument, so the way to "fix it" is _don't send that argument_.

Comment: Yes, but I need a way of SSH authentication and because open() doesn't take password, I'm kinda lost now.